# What's the best way of centering text inside a rounded container?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to horizontally center this toggle switch that has two lines of text :
https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-ritchie-egmqmr?file=/index.html

[image]

But I need it to be horizontally centered like this :

[image]

Comment: Isn't that vertically centered?

Comment: Don't have a div inside a span.

Comment: The best way to vertically or horizontally center something is to make the parent `display: flex;` and add `justify-content: center` and `align-items: center` to the parent as well. Unfortunately your code is a little flawed in a few other ways, like divs inside spans and `onClick` handlers on spans. Use a button element instead of a span and remove the border and background, and then make the button as wide as your `::after` element - that would be a start

Answer (score 2):

Just add a main div, that wraps the whole container. And add the following styles to it:

```
 .main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
      .main {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Prompt&display=swap");
      .toggle {
        width: 175px;
        height: 46px;
        font-stretch: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        text-align: left;
        border: solid 1px #ebebeb;
        border-radius: 30px;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        place-items: center;
        margin-right: 0;
        font-family: "Prompt", sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #333;
        outline: 0;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: all 500ms;
        margin-left: 0;
      }

      span {
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        user-select: none;
        color: #333;
      }

      span.selected {
        color: white;
      }

      .toggle::after {
        background-color: #333;
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
        left: 3px;
        top: 4px;
        width: 84px;
        border-radius: 30px;
        background-image: linear-gradient(111deg, #1dceb4 17%, #8fd534 87%);
        height: 38px;
        transition: all 200ms ease-in;
      }

      .rightSelected::after {
        left: calc(50% + 4px);
      }

      .label-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: auto;
        width: fit-content;
      }
      p.standard {
        padding-bottom: 1px;
      }
      p.express {
        padding-bottom: 2px;
      }
      p {
        margin: 0;
        margin-block-start: 0;
        margin-block-end: 0;
        font-family: Prompt;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-align: right;
      }

      p.delivery {
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 10px;
        margin-top: -6px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="toggle" id="toggle">
        <span onclick="select()">
          <div class="label-container">
            <p class="standard">Standard</p>
            <p class="delivery">Delivery</p>
          </div>
        </span>
        <span onclick="select()">
          <div class="label-container">
            <p class="express">Express</p>
            <p class="delivery">Delivery</p>
          </div>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      let toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");
      console.log(toggle);

      function select() {
        toggle.classList.toggle("rightSelected");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think this is what you wanted: **https://k8wo13.csb.app/**
[image]